# Min stack solution not working for leetcode

Tags: python

I'm trying a leetcode min stack problem and my code is not working, tried finding a solution but can't see what's wrong. It seems to work for most inputs but fails "

> ["MinStack","push","push","push","top","pop","getMin","pop","getMin","pop","push","top","getMin","push","top","getMin","pop","getMin"]
>   [[],[2147483646],[2147483646],[2147483647],[],[],[],[],[],[],[2147483647],[],[],[-2147483648],[],[],[],[]]" .

```
class MinStack:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.stack = []
        self.count = 0
        self.minEle = -1

    def push(self, x: int) -> None:
        if self.count == 0:
            self.minEle = x
            self.stack.append(x)
        elif x < self.minEle:
            self.stack.append(2*x - self.minEle)
            self.minEle = x
        elif x >= self.minEle:
            self.stack.append(x)

        self.count += 1

    def pop(self) -> None:
        y = self.stack.pop()
        if y < self.minEle:
            self.minEle = 2*self.minEle - y
        self.count -= 1

    def top(self) -> int:
        if self.count >=1:
            return self.stack[(self.count - 1)]
        else:
            return 0

    def getMin(self) -> int:
        return self.minEle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class MinStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sc = []
        self.sm = []
# @param x, an integer
# @return an integer
def push(self, x):
    self.sc.append(x)
    if x <= self.getMin():
        self.sm.append(x)
    return x

# @return nothing
def pop(self):
    if self.sc.pop() == self.getMin():
        self.sm.pop()

# @return an integer
def top(self):
    return self.sc[-1]

# @return an integer
def getMin(self):
    try:
        return self.sm[-1]
    except IndexError:
        return self.top()
obj = MinStack()
obj.push(-2)
obj.push(0)
obj.push(-3)
print(obj.getMin())
obj.pop()
print(obj.top()) 
print(obj.getMin())  
param_3 = obj.top()
param_4 = obj.getMin()
```